# Реализация оплаты картой в приложении iOS

Tags: ios, интернет-магазин, платежи, paypal

Делаю приложение под iOS для интернет-магазина. Нужно добавить возможность оплаты товаров по карте прям в приложении. На сайте магазина реализован эквайринг через Альфа-банк. Что мне нужно, чтобы проводить платежи непосредственно в приложении?

Как я поняла, и как мне сказали в банке, нужно открывать в WebView страницу с их платежным шлюзом и передавать туда только сумму покупки. Все остальное происходит на их стороне, а по завершению мне возвращаются некоторые данные, например номер транзакции. Я не понимаю как реализовать переход? Может быть есть пример, где это реализовано?

Как работать с API банка или как делать эту реализацию через web-view? Есть хоть какой нибудь туториал?

Comment: Можно открывать webview. Можно работать с API банка напрямую запросами из нативного приложения.

Comment: такой вопрос уже был: [Как сделать оплату услуг в приложение/игре iOS.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233848)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Как сделать оплату услуг в приложение/игре iOS.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233848/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-ios)

Comment: В этом вопросе описано как реализовать in-app purches. А мне нужна оплата картой физических покупок. Как работать с апи банка или как работать с вебвью для оплаты? На эти вопросы ответа там нет..

Comment: я бы предложил добавить тэгов - проблема никакого отношения к iOS (например) не имеет.